# Accepting interviews while waiting to sign contact for a research position (as a backup)

Tags: postdocs, job-search, interview

If a postdoc receives a conditional offer of employment, is it still a good idea for them to tentatively accept any further interview offers from another university which come during the waiting period, basically as a backup?

I suppose if one is committed to the first position, it won't offend them if the candidate is theoretically still interviewing?

Answer (score 4):

It is fine to continue interviewing until you accept an offer. There shouldn't be any ethical issue with that. You might leave yourself vulnerable to the withdrawal of an offer (some situations, some places) or not.

You can even continue the negotiation (better salary) if you like, though that carries risks as well. You can also ask for an extension of the offer. But you aren't bound by the acts of others; the offer.

Don't worry about "offending" anyone. That is an orthogonal issue. You have a responsibility to yourself until you make some commitment to another. Only then does it bind you in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can continue interviewing. Even if you have an offer they could still withdraw it (happened to me!). And who knows ... maybe you will even get a better offer.
But once you signed the contract you should stop interviewing elsewhere.